# Probability of selecting an element from a set

Tags: statistics, probability, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution

The expected probability of randomly selecting an element from a set of n elements is P=1.0/n .
Suppose I check P using an unbiased method sufficiently many times. What is the distribution type of P? It is clear that P is not normally distributed, since cannot be negative. Thus, may I correctly assume that P is [gamma distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)? And if yes, what are the parameters of this distribution? 
Histogram of probabilities of selecting an element from 100-element set for 1000 times is shown [here](http://img267.imageshack.us/my.php?image=imageqa2.png).

Is there any way to convert this to a standard distribution

Now supposed that the observed probability of selecting the given element was P* (P* != P). How can I estimate whether the bias is statistically significant?

EDIT: This is not a homework. I'm doing a hobby project and I need this piece of statistics for it. I've done my last homework ~10 years ago:-)

Comment: This is not a homework. I'm doing a hobby project and I need this piece of statistics for it. I've done my last homework ~10 years ago:-)

Comment: Doesn't this all depend on your random number generator? If a random number generator was *perfect*, the probability is always 1/n for every pick regardless of number of picks and after 1000 picks, each element should have been picked 1000/n times - I seem to miss something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With repetitions, your distribution will be binomial. So let X be the number of times you select some fixed object, with M total selections

P{ X = x } = ( M choose x ) * (1/N)^x * (N-1/N)^(M-x)

You may find this difficult to compute for large N. It turns out that for sufficiently large N, this actually converges to a normal distribution with probability 1 (Central Limit theorem).

In case P{X=x} will be given by a normal distribution. The mean will be M/N and the variance will be M * (1/N) * ( N-1) / N.

Comment: "this actually converges to a normal distribution with probability 1": Nope, the convergence is in distribution (after suitable rescaling). The difference between both is not relevant here, but mathematically your statement is very wrong.

Comment: The convergence is also much slower for p close to 0 or 1, such that N has to be extremely large.

Answer (score 3):

This is a clear [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_Distribution) with p=1/(number of elements) and n=(number of trials).

To test whether the observed result differs significantly from the expected result, you can do the [binomial test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test).

The dice examples on the two Wikipedia pages should give you some good guidance on how to formulate your problem.  In your 100-element, 1000 trial example, that would be like rolling a 100-sided die 1000 times.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you want the Binomial distribution.  Your question seems to imply an interest in a continuous approximation to it, though.  It can actually be [approximated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) by the normal distribution, and also by the [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Poisson_approximation).

Answer (score 0):

Is your distribution a [discrete uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29)?